understanding adjectives and verbs
I just started learning and this is a bit confusing:
During my research I found this word: 急いで which is an adverb (hurriedly) and I think comes from 急 (sudden)
My question is, if I see a word like that which ends in ~いで, how do I know whether it's the te-form of a verb, or an adverb like in this case.
Or rather, can I turn any adjective into a pseudo verb and conjugate it like I would any verb?
In fact, some sources I read say the meaning of 急いで is to hurry, as if it's a verb.

急いで【いそいで】 is the regular "te" form of the verb 急ぐ【いそぐ】 ("to hurry, to rush, to make haste"). It's not an adverb, grammatically speaking in the modern language.  The "te" form of any verb may be used as a kind of request or gentle imperative / command, which may account for your last comment.  What source did you find that stated that 急いで is an adverb?

It's a little strange to me that it has its own dictionary entry at all, since there's nothing about it to my knowledge that would warrant separating it from the 急ぐ entry.

Also worth pointing out that the te-form can be/is often used adverbially. ペンを使って書いた is more naturally translated as "he wrote using a pen" rather than "He used a pen and wrote".

@user3856370, granted, but even so that doesn't make the "-te" form an adverb, any more than the "-ing" form in English is an adverb.

@EiríkrÚtlendi True enough, but it hopefully makes it easier to see how the confusion might arise.

急いで is the simple te-form of 急ぐ, and 急ぐ is a plain godan verb. That is, 急いで roughly means "hurry up and", but it can be translated into an English adverb. 急いで by itself is not listed in dictionaries (at least, not in monolingual ones) as an independent adverb.
急な【きゅうな】 ("sudden") is a completely different na-adjective and has nothing to do with 急ぐ or 急いで, except that they happen to share the same kanji.
There are cases where a te-form in Japanese expresses the manner of motion and is typically translated into an English adverb or adverbial expression:

黙って聞く

Literally: to shut up and listen
Naturally: to listen quietly


歩いて学校に行く: to go to school on foot
焦って答える: to answer nervously

